# W/ManagedChannelImpl: [{0}] Failed to resolve name. status={1}

Tags: android, firebase, resolve

I am working on and android app and, I implemented FireStore and now I keep on getting this error, it repeats aswell.

```
 W/ManagedChannelImpl: [{0}] Failed to resolve name. status={1}
```

Anyone knows what this is?

Comment: Have you tried closing the AVD and opening it again?

Comment: As @Mohammad Desouky said, I have this when I turn on Airplane mode. I wonder which plugin is doing it because it shouldn't keep spamming it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@AlleyOOP is right. Restarting emulator worked for me.

Answer (score 22):

There is no Connection to the internet in the device which your app running on!

Comment: I have this when I turn on Airplane mode. I wonder which plugin is doing it because it shouldn't keep spamming it.

Comment: Quick question is it something i should be worried about in a production app. I have a stream which fetches data and every so often the internet drops. I read that firestore has offline support but i keep seeing this error logged which makes me think about production app. should i be worried

Comment: No, as long as your error checking i.e. the ConnectionState, is correct then there shouldn't be any issues. This is due to network connections as mentioned above. So will happen occasionally on a production app if the user disconnects from their network.

Answer (score 1):

The above-mentioned issue occurred to me, this happens because of network connection. 
Try turning on and of your network connection if it is a physical device.

If Virtual device,
Restart the device

Answer (score 0):

issue in your network. change network provider solved for me